# I get Error Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration in c#

Tags: c#

I have written this code in C#:

```
public bool AsyncInjection { get; set; } = false;

public uint TimeOut { get; set; } = 5000;
```

And after built I got this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CrtC.png)

> Error Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>   Error Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Can you help me, please?

Comment: what you want to do, assign initial value to property ? which version of c# are you using?

Comment: Actualy no I can sand u all code from this class

Comment: I am not with my visual studio, so i cannot help you with code but with behaviour!